# "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, centos6.5

I've spent 5 hours trying to resolve this issue.  I've used every suggestive link that was relevant to my issue that Google listed.  Nothing seems to work.

The OS is CentOS 6.5 and has Apache, PHP, and MySQL installed.  I have several WordPress intranet sites working for almost a year with my subdomain xxxxx.xxxx.com.

First of all, I updated PHP 5.3.3 to the latest version.  After that I got the error that MySQL extensions were not installed.  I followed the different resolutions I could find and could not get a resolve.  I therefore decided to remove php and install the older version I originally had.  Since that time I am running into three problems.

1. My domain now only shows the Apache page whereas it use to show my website;
2. When I try to find out what php version I have by using the command php -v I would get what version was installed.  After removing the updated version and installing the older one I get the error "php: command not found";
3. When I try to remove the older version I can't find it's install location and phpinfo.php doesn't work (may have put it in the wrong place)

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you trying to update or install php on your server? (which commands, etc)?

Comment: rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

Comment: I got php 5.5 installed and I can get the version via php -v in command line.  However, I am back at the following error "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."'

Comment: The MySQL API has been deprecated. I suspect that that's the problem. Revise your code to use PDO or the mysqli_ API

Comment: See below, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem with my centos 7 installtion with php-fpm ..
the solution was to install php-gd and php-pdo packages. those were the essential packages somehow required to make this all work.. good day

Answer (score 0):

"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

For others who may run across this same problem.  The majority of the help I found Googling the problem dealt with editing the php.ini to uncomment the MySql extensions.  Some even go as far as to say that there is only one thing that causes this problem.

However, what resolved my problem was actually downloading and installing php55-mysql to include the extensions.  So be sure to take a look at that as well.